# Load balancer and celery result backends

Tags: celery

I have a task that takes approximately 3 minutes to run. It pulls data from a remote server and makes cpu-intensive analysis on it. This task will be invoked by an api call. Upon the api call, i am planning to give client a unique task id and assign the task to a celery worker. Then the client will poll the server with the given task id to see if the task is completed by celery worker and its result it saved to a result backend. I think of using nginx, gunicorn, flask and dockerize them for a easy deploy in case i need to distribute this architecture across multiple machines.

The problem is that the client may poll different servers due to load balancer and if not handled well, the polled server’s celery’s result backend might not have the task’s result but other server’s celery result backend has it.

Is it possible to use a single result backend over multiple celery instances and make different celery instances wuery the same result backend? What might be other possible ways to solve this other than using cloud storage like S3?

Would I have this problem only if I have multiple machines or would it happen even if I have multiple gunicorn instances in a single machine where nginx acts as a load balancer on them?

Comment: Isn't all celery instance uses the same celery backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that it is possible to use a single result backend by all Celery workers, but that is the only setting that makes sense! Same goes for the broker in most cases, unless you have a complicated Celery infrastructure with exchanges, and complicated routes...